# Connect directly to subsite without viewing home

Tags: 2010, permissions

I have:

- SP2010 rented from a company. 1 site collection

I would like some people to ONLY access a sub site without seeing the homepage. Is this possible?

I have tried but I get a message saying that you are not authorized to view but when I give them permission for the home page, they can

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to break permissions inheritance on the Home page in the Site Pages library to include only those who you wish to have access to view it.  For those that you do not wish to have access, you're going to need to give them some alternative URL to get into the site.

Typically when someone tries to access http://sp.domain.com/sites/thesite/thesubsite, they get redirected automatically to the home.aspx page.  For users that don't have access, they'll get access denied even though they have the ability to access other content.  You'll need to create some other landing page for those users and provide them the URL so they can get into the subsite.

Comment: Ok, let me try that, will keep you updated.

Comment: Wow - you are right.. Thank you!, Would put +1 but need a rep of 15. Thank you though

Comment: Is there any reason why people cannot access */SitePages/Home.aspx but they can access all the other stuff, lists, folders etc.

Comment: That's the way its working because that's what you asked for.  If the users are not supposed to see anything at all in the subsite, then you need to remove their access to the site altogether.

Comment: I agree. When I go to a sub site I can access all the other information which is great, Lists, folder etc. however I cannot see the subsites Home page. I get a Error: Access Denied . This is on the subsite.. Thanks

Comment: Right, that's what you said you wanted, for certain users to not view the home page of the subsite.  If that isn't the desired affect, then reset the permissions so they can.  You'll then need to distribute to the few select users a URL to some other place in the subsite in order to bypass the Home.aspx page.

Comment: aaaa ok... Sorry Maybe I have not made my self clear... I do not want the user to view the HOME PAGE on the MAIN TOP site. But I do want them ONLY to see the subsite and all its content.

Comment: Then in that scenario, you simply remove the user permissions from the root site, reset the permissions inheritance of the Site Pages library in the subsite, and provide the users the URL to the subsite.  If they try to view the root site, they'll get access denied and have access to all content in the subsite..

Comment: Yes, you are right. I do understand the logic. But I still get this problem. I will investigate with the company and let you know. I do not know if the permission pass through right away.