# Connect directly to subsite without viewing home (Part 2)

Tags: 2010, site-template, site

I have:

```
SP2010 rented from a company. 1 site collection
```

I would like some people to ONLY access a sub site without seeing the homepage. Is this possible?

I have tried but I get a message saying that you are not authorized to view but when I give them permission for the home page, they can

[Continuation from this Forum, Base subject is the same but with a twist :-|](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30345/connect-directly-to-subsite-without-viewing-home)

Now... the new INFORMATION, I have created a template which has nothing except a company logo, not the default one.

When I use the template (My Saved one) and I only want the user to access a sub-site, for some strange reason they MUST have access the the top level site...if not, I get an error message.

If on the other hand I use the OEM temples what comes with SP1, I can have the user accessing the sub-site WITHOUT the need to access the top level site. This is a strange one for me..

The sub-site has nothing from the top level site, no logo, module, NADA de NADA!
Any thoughts

home.aspx code

```
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%> <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WikiEditPage" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"       %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/> - 
    <SharePoint:ListItemProperty runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    <span>
        <SharePoint:DocumentFolderName runat="server" id="PageFolderName" AppendSeparatorArrow = "true"/>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-WikiPageNameEditor-Display" id="wikiPageNameDisplay" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ListItemProperty runat="server"/>
    </span>
    <span class="ms-WikiPageNameEditor-Edit" style="display:none;" id="wikiPageNameEdit" runat="server">
        <asp:TextBox id="wikiPageNameEditTextBox" runat="server"/>
    </span>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageDescription" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="4">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderPageImage" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:AlphaImage ID=onetidtpweb1 Src="/_layouts/images/wiki.png" Width=145 Height=54 Alt="" Runat="server"/></asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <meta name="CollaborationServer" content="SharePoint Team Web Site" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var navBarHelpOverrideKey = "WSSEndUser";
    </script>
    <SharePoint:RssLink runat="server"/>
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent UIVersion="4" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <SharePoint:CssRegistration runat="server" Name="wiki.css" />
    </ContentTemplate></SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMiniConsole" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:FormComponent TemplateName="WikiMiniConsole" ControlMode="Display" runat="server" id="WikiMiniConsole"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderLeftActions" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:RecentChangesMenu runat="server" id="RecentChanges"/>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:UIVersionedContent runat="server" UIVersion="3" Id="PlaceHolderWebDescription">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div class="ms-webpartpagedescription"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Description" runat="server"/></div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>
    <asp:UpdatePanel
           id="updatePanel"
           runat="server"
           UpdateMode="Conditional"
           ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder UIVersion="4" runat="server">
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonButton
                    id="btnWikiEdit"
                    RibbonCommand="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.Edit"
                    runat="server"
                    Text="edit"/>
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonButton
                    id="btnWikiSave"
                    RibbonCommand="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.SaveAndStop"
                    runat="server"
                    Text="edit"/>
                <SharePoint:SPRibbonButton
                    id="btnWikiRevert"
                    RibbonCommand="Ribbon.WikiPageTab.EditAndCheckout.SaveEdit.Menu.SaveEdit.Revert"
                    runat="server"
                    Text="Revert"/>
            </SharePoint:VersionedPlaceHolder>
            <SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField id="WikiField" FieldName="WikiField" ControlMode="Display" runat="server"><div class="ExternalClass44E19850FE3C4C8394B62A00300331C0"><table id="layoutsTable" style="width:100%"><tbody><tr style="vertical-align:top"><td style="width:66.6%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><h1 class="ms-rteElement-H1B" style="margin-bottom:0px"><span><span>PIB</span></span></h1>
<p>This section of the sites looks at content production &amp; script production for the Teleprompter<br /></p></div></div></td>
<td style="width:33.3%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-outer" style="width:100%"><div class="ms-rte-layoutszone-inner"><br />
<div id="vid_e82c931e-53ac-4043-9c42-a207770c2a1f" style="display:none"></div></div></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
<span id="layoutsData" style="display:none">false,false,2</span></div></SharePoint:EmbeddedFormField>
            <WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="Bottom" Title="loc:Bottom"><ZoneTemplate></ZoneTemplate></WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="WikiField" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnWikiRevert" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnWikiSave" />
    </Triggers>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Access is determined by the permissions you set up, not by the template itself. When you create a sub-site, make sure your select specific permissions, not permissions inherited from the parent site.

Comment: Yes, indeed I have, this was stated in the first post and has been done. The sub-site does not inherit permissions from the top site. I have given the user(s) direct permissions on only the sub-site.

Comment: Maybe your template is using a script, a stylesheet or other content that resides at the top level? In this case your users will be blocked. You'll need to either open permissions for that specific content or change the links.

Comment: I think you are right, how would one know if this is the case from the above code. I cannot see something obvious.